# $(this).html() not working in IE but works fine in Chrome

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-11

I am parsing XML file in Jquery with **jquery-2.1.0.js** plug in. it works fine in chrome.

**Sample :**

```
 $(this).find("XMLTag").each(function () {
                var result = $(this).html();
});
```

Above statements returns XML nodes which resides inside "XMLTag".
This works perfect in Chrome.

But in IE (I have **IE11**) **result** returned **undefined**.

Can anybody help me out this?